# Exception when Loading TableViewCell from NIB

Tags: uitableview, xcode4.2

I want to load TableViewCell from NIB so IssueTableCell.xib and my code is here:

```
static NSString *issueTableCellId = @"IssueTableCell";

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:issueTableCellId];
NSInteger index = indexPath.row;

NSDictionary *d = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
titleLabel.text= [d objectForKey:@"Name"];


UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
imageView.image=nil;

[self setCoverOfIssueAtIndex:index completionBlock:^(UIImage *img) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [table_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]];
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        imageView.image=img;
    });
}];

NKLibrary *nkLib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];
NKIssue *nkIssue = [nkLib issueWithName:[self nameOfIssueAtIndex:index]];
UIProgressView *downloadProgress = (UIProgressView *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
UILabel *tapLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
if(nkIssue.status==NKIssueContentStatusAvailable) {
    tapLabel.text=@"TAP TO READ";
    tapLabel.alpha=1.0;
    downloadProgress.alpha=0.0;
} else {
    if(nkIssue.status==NKIssueContentStatusDownloading) {
        downloadProgress.alpha=1.0;
        tapLabel.alpha=0.0;
    } else {
        downloadProgress.alpha=0.0;
        tapLabel.alpha=1.0;
        tapLabel.text=@"TAP TO DOWNLOAD";
    }

}
return cell; }
```

and my exception is

> UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

the error comes because compiler can't find reuseidentifier & it means your cell is nil

also maintain reuseidentifier properly so compiler can reuse it.

you should try this after dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

You have to  check for nil and if cell is nil then create new cell 
like this:

if(cell == nil)

{

//create new cell here...

}

Comment: i try it but still the exception is happen :(